# Study of all published works of Bertrand Russell on foundations of mathematics: Please recommend his works.

Tags: logic, philosophy, foundations

Study of all published works of Bertrand Russell on foundations of mathematics: Please recommend his works.

I think Bertrand Russell was a special mind and I set a goal for myself
to study all his published works, in one year beginning now.

I start with "Introduction to Mathematical Philosophy" which so far
seems accessible for beginners.

Can you please recommend some of his published works that I must include in my study,
or works that you think were not so good, etc. ? I am interested only in his work
on foundations of mathematics.

Thank you

Comment: Try "Principia Mathematica", his huge book in mathematical logic, written together with  Alfred N. Whitehead. You may find this waaaaaaaaay less accessible, even for professional mathematicians...

Comment: Strongly recommend reading Frank Ramsey's commentary on Russell's theory of types as well ( after you read Russell's theory of types )

Comment: I was warned about Principia, that I should not read it unless I am interested in history of mathematics, which I am not. I just want to learn more about the foundations of math. But I want to explore the philosophy behind it, not just start from logic and set theory for example, and ignore the philosophy behind it.

Comment: As I recall Principia is page after page after page of proofs using formal logic with few if any words in English or any other human readable language. There are good reasons why this method of mathematical exposition did not catch on.

Comment: There are long stretches of the *Principia* that are written in prose. But there are longer stretches that are not, and I agree that your time would probably be better spent elsewhere.

Comment: For future readers, note that PM is full of issues. As described in [Russell and Godel](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/bulletin-of-symbolic-logic/article/russell-and-godel/0C347F171985A54395CDA89D31C4A59A), "[in] Principia Mathematica [...] the syntax is never precisely described, and the axioms and rules of inference are presented in a way that mixes together the syntax with its intended meaning. The formalism appears to be inextricably tied to its informal interpretation. [...] it is this last feature of Russell’s logic that seems to have led to some misunderstandings on his part."

Comment: Russell himself admitted as much in a postscript to a 1943 article by Godel: "His great ability, as shown in his previous work, makes me think it highly probable that many of his criticisms of me are justified. The writing of Principia Mathematica was completed thirty-three years ago, and obviously, in view of subsequent advances in the subject, it needs amending in various ways. [...] I must therefore ask the reader to give Dr. Gödel’s work the attention that it deserves, and to form his own critical judgment on it."

Comment: The useful bits of Russell's work on his ramified theory of types and the later version with the philosophically unjustifiable axiom of reducibility have been abstracted out, given proper precise formulation by other logicians, and studied elsewhere, not in PM. If you're interested in foundations of mathematics, it is far better to read the writings of logicians such as Boolos.

Answer (score 3):

Russell's 1903 *The Principles of Mathematics* (not to be confused with the similarly-named *Principia Mathematica*, written by Russell with Whitehead a decade later) is a good place to start, and should keep you busy for quite some time -- it's about 600 pages long and is available as a free PDF (it's in the public domain) from a number of sources.

Comment: Is it accessible for beginners? What prerequisites does it assume?

Comment: It doesn't seem to assume any specific knowledge other than that elusive thing, "mathematical maturity".